# MVVM WPF DataBinding troubleshooting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

In following the MVVM architecture for WPF, learning WPF DataBindings.  I have a single instance of an object instantiated at runtime with the XAML code `<p:MemoryPersistentStorageBridge x:Key="persistentMemoryBridge" />` within Window Resources.  I am trying to obtain data from the object instance, and plop it into a TextBox as an example, but I am not getting any text in that text box.

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="UserConsole.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:PollPublicDataStock;assembly=PollPublicDataStock"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserConsole"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="900" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <p:MemoryPersistentStorageBridge x:Key="persistentMemoryBridge" />
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid Name="grid1" >
         <!--  layout defintions  -->
        <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource persistentMemoryBridge}"   Text="{Binding Path=GetConnectionString}" Margin="0,327,31,491" Foreground="Black" Background="Yellow"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind:

```cs
public class MemoryPersistentStorageBridge {

    public MemoryPersistentStorageBridge() {

    }

   public string GetConnectionString() {
        return "THISTEXTSHOULDAPPEARINTEXTBOXBUTSADLYDOESNOT";
    }

}
```

Comment: A quick look in the `Output` window would have shown the Binding error(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to bind to a method. You need to bind to a property. Or else use an [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.methodname%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

So you could do this:

```
public class MemoryPersistentStorageBridge {

     public MemoryPersistentStorageBridge() {

    }

    public string ConnectionString {
        get { return GetConnectionString(); }
    }

   public string GetConnectionString() {
        return "THISTEXTSHOULDAPPEARINTEXTBOXBUTSADLYDOESNOT";
    }

}
```

or even:

```
public class MemoryPersistentStorageBridge {

     public MemoryPersistentStorageBridge() {

    }

    public string ConnectionString {
        get { return "THISTEXTSHOULDAPPEARINTEXTBOXBUTSADLYDOESNOT"; }
    }

}
```

Of course, in either case we are not handling changing the property and notifying the binding of a change.

The other option is to use the ObjectDataProvider to wrap your method. This is illustrated in the link I provided. But would look something like this:

```
<ObjectDataProvider ObjectInstance="{StaticResource persistentMemoryBridge}"
                  MethodName="GetConnectionString" x:Key="connectionString">
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is correct... I have to wait to acccept this answer, but in the meantime...being new to DataBinding and new to WPF, what is the best way to learn these details.  I'm finding the MSDN documents unclear.

Comment: @sammarcow The MSDN documents are pretty good and there are many books. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx   Early in the description it talks about binding to properties.